# How to query where at least one element exists in a list?

Tags: c#, list, listbox

I'm trying to query a list of Movies based on customer search. Genres is a list in Movies so that means Movies can have multiple genres. When searching, customers can select which genres they want to look for through a multi-select list.

My problem is that my code is querying Movies where it contains every genre that is selected, rather than querying Movies where at least one of the genres is selected. (omitted other arguments and query code to save space)

```
public ActionResult DisplaySearchResults(int[] SelectedGenres) //selected genres from multiselect list
{
    List<Movie> SelectedMovies = new List<Movie>();
    SelectedMovies = db.Movies.ToList();
    var query = from r in db.Movies.Include("Genres")
                select r;

    if (SelectedGenres == null || SelectedGenres.Count() == 0) 
    {
        ViewBag.SelectedGenre = "No genre was selected";
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (int GenreID in SelectedGenres)
        {
            //need to query where there's at least one genre, not all
            //EX.Western and Horror selected should return movies that have either western or horror as a genre, not both.
            query = query.Where(r => r.Genres.Any(x => x.GenreID == GenreID));
        }
    }

    SelectedMovies = query.ToList();
    return View("Index", SelectedMovies);
 }
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: I need to query the Movies list where at least one of the genres selected exists, not all of them. For example, if the customer selects western and thriller for genres, it should query movies that have EITHER western or thriller as a genre, not both. My current code is querying the latter.

Comment: is the Genre a list of items inside the movie object ?

Comment: yes! sorry i didn't specify, i don't think i was very clear with my question.

Comment: Why do you assign `SelectedMovies` to a new list and then turn around on the next line and assign it to the list from the db? And then you don't use it until the end, when you do a third assignment to the query..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do what you want. I've combined some of your logic into the query to demonstrate how you can test for `selectedGenres` to be `null` or empty in the query itself.

Basically it says, select all Movies (and include Genres) where one of the following is true:

- `selectedGenres` is `null`
- `selectedGenres` is empty
- the `selectedGenres` list contains at least one of the `GenreIDs` from the movie's `Genres` list

Here's the code:

```
public ActionResult DisplaySearchResults(int[] selectedGenres)
{
    var filteredMovies = db.Movies.Include("Genres")
        .Where(movie => selectedGenres == null ||
                        !selectedGenres.Any() ||
                        movie.Genres.Any(genre => selectedGenres.Contains(genre.GenreID)))
        .ToList();

    return View("Index", filteredMovies);
}
```

Comment: this worked, thank you so much!! i only used part of the code since i had other stuff i needed to add in as well:                 query = query.Where(r => r.Genres.Any(genre => SelectedGenres.Contains(genre.GenreID)));

Comment: Great, glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 2):

I imagine your problem (i'm not exactly sure what your problem is, but this is what sticks out to me) is in the lines

```
foreach (int GenreID in SelectedGenres)
{
    //need to query where there's at least one genre, not all
    //EX.Western and Horror selected should return movies that have either western or horror as a genre, not both.
    query = query.Where(r => r.Genres.Any(x => x.GenreID == GenreID));
}
```

since you are overwriting query with the results of query.Where().  Maybe something like this would work for you instead since you will be saving the results of each query.Where() to your returned list rather than overwriting query with the results of query.Where().

```
foreach (int GenreID in SelectedGenres)
{
    //saving the results of each query.Where call to the SelectedMovies List
    SelectedMovies.AddRange(query.Where(r => r.Genres.Any(x => x.GenreID == GenreID)).ToList());
}
```

Comment: thank you! but this still didn't work :( i may have not been clear with my question. I also don't think my queries are being overwritten in my original code. they're just getting more narrowed every time it goes through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

after a while doing some testing this is what you need :

```
 List<Movie> FilteredMovies = SelectedMovies.Where(x => x.Genres.Any(y=> SelectedGenres.Contains(y))).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with this code: 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Contains<Genre>(IQueryable<Genre>, Genre)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<Genre>'.

Comment: this is weird... an int array should be have the contains function,  maybe a toList().contains() will do the trick